# SQL query result to array/List

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand

Following is the C# code for querying the DB to get the list of users id:

```
int id;
con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionStr);
con.Open();
id = 180;
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select userid from UserProfile where grpid=@id", con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader["userid"]));
    }
}

con.Close();
```

> Output: 5629

Actually, the list of `Users` having `grpid = 180` are **5629, 5684, 5694**.

How can I read the results in a list or an array ?

Comment: not exactly sure what you're asking, What do you mean by "read the results in list" ?

Comment: try to write  `while (reader.Read())`  instead of  `if (reader.Read())`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024226/how-to-generate-liststring-from-sql-query) shows you how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate List<String> from SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024226/how-to-generate-liststring-from-sql-query)

Answer (score 8):

simply:

```
List<int> results = new List<int>();
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        results.Add((int)reader["userid"]));
    }
}
// use results
```

However, you might find a tool like "Dapper" a useful time saver here

```
var results = con.Query<int>("Select userid from UserProfile where grpid=@id",
    new { id }).AsList();
```

Comment: @CodeNotFound indeed

Comment: Thanks much for the quick help.

Comment: @JG'sSpark emphasis: I *strongly* recommend tools like Dapper instead of raw ADO.NET; it saves a lot of time and unnecessary bugs; I'm very biased, though

Comment: Any reference link for Dapper ? would be more useful to me

Comment: @JG'sSpark https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/ or https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Readme.md

Comment: Sure, Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 5):

Simply define a List, and use like:

```
List<string> Users = new List<string>();
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Users.Add(reader[0].ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
var userIds = new List<int>();
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        userIds.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use this extension method:

```
public static class DbExtensions
{
    public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IDataReader reader, int columnOrdinal = 0)
    {
        var list = new List<T>();
        while(reader.Read())
            list.Add((T)reader[columnOrdinal]);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in this way:

```
List<int> userIdList;
using (var con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionStr))
{
    using(var command = new SqlCommand("Select userid from UserProfile where grpid=@id", con))
    {
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
       con.Open();
       using (SqlDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader())
          userIdList = rd.ToList<int>();
    }
}
```